# How to call a fragment activity from an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am actually using in Android Studio for my Android application. I have imported a module in my project. The module consist of fragment activities. I have compiled the module into the gradle app file and also included the module in the gradle settings file. I want to call the fragment activity with a button from an activity, but when I am clicking on the button the application crashes.  
I have declared the fragment activity in my AndroidManifest.xml file but the application keeps on crashing.

Error when the application is crashing:

[image]
I am using the following code to call the fragment activity :

```
Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
starActivity(new Intent(projectActivity.this, moduleFragmentActiviy.class));
}
});
```

I assume that I am getting this error because I am calling a fragment activity from an activity directly. If this is the case, may I know how to call the fragment activity please.

Comment: It would be great if you share the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to edit that module source code, that the right way to do this is to add intent-filter to FragmentActivity.

In module's AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".FragmentAcitivity" >  
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.YOUR_ACTION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And in MainActivity of main module:

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.YOUR_ACTION"));
    }
});
```

*... and I hope you use UpperCamelCase for class naming*

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your manifest file? The syntax looks correct. As said in the error message - please check that activity class is declared, and, specifically, it is declared in **manifest file**.